# regex for plain email and mailto links, but not http basic auth

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a regular expression to meet these conditions:

[DON'T MATCH]

```
dont:match@example.com
```

[MATCH]

```
mailto:match@example.com
match@example.com
<p>match@example.com</p>
```

I can match the last two, but the first example (DON'T MATCH) is also matched.

How do I make sure an email is only valid if it's plain or proceeded by `mailto:`, but not just a `:`?

http://rubular.com/r/HvldBe4Ew9

Regex:

`(?<=mailto:)?([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)`

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: @PedroLobito Python2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anchors `^` and `$` for matching string start/end if the strings are passed as separate values:

```
(?<=>)(?:mailto:)?([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)(?=<)
```

Or, getting rid of capturing groups:

```
(?<=>)(?:mailto:)?[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?=<)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/hqWwRur1Rf)

Please note that you have an issue in `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]`: the hyphen symbol should not appear unescaped in the middle of the character class.

Comment: I also need to match something like `<p>match@example.com</p>` (or any other HTML tag around it), so I can't use `^` in the front.

Comment: Good, here is a solution: add the look-arounds with `>` and `<`.

Comment: How do I adjust the regex to not match include the `mailto:` part in the match but only match an email address if it's proceeded by `mailto:`?

Comment: Have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/jH6lD9/1. Using `(?<=>)(?:mailto:)?([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)(?=<)`, you can get the email captured in Group 1. In Python, you can refer to that capture group using `.group(1)`. See http://ideone.com/1ZfVIO for sample Python2.7 demo. Let me know if it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

No need for`a-zA-Z`, just use `A-Z` and make the regex case insensitive with `re.IGNORECASE`.
Also make sure you use

`^` Assert position at the beginning of a line
and
`$` Assert position at the end of a line

---

Python Example:

```
import re

match = re.search(r"^(?:mailto:)?([A-Z0-9_.+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+\.[\tA-Z0-9-.]+)$", email, re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/cI1eD6/1

---

Regex explanation:

```
^(mailto:)?([A-Z0-9_.+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z0-9-.]+)$

Options: Case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of a line «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(mailto:)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character string “mailto:” literally «mailto:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([A-Z0-9_.+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z0-9-.]+)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9_.+-]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
      A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
      A single character from the list “_.+” «_.+»
      The literal character “-” «-»
   Match the character “@” literally «@»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9-]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
      A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
      The literal character “-” «-»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9-.]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
      A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
      A single character from the list “-.” «-.»
Assert position at the end of a line «$»
```

Comment: This allow an empty `mailto:` with no address, how would you ensure there is a valid email address too?

Comment: The regex above won't match an empty email, you can test it at https://regex101.com/r/cI1eD6/1